# Creating multiple files with sys.argv syntax

Tags: python, file-io, syntax

I am doing several things 1) reading in a file with 2 columns, each a float, to establish a range
2) reading lines in a second file, comparing columns to that input range file
3) writing to a new file the whole line of second file if certain values are within a set range from file1 and naming that new file with column1 and column2 from rangefile

Every time this condition is correct, I want to create a file that is based off the range. It should loop through the entire second file checking and writing to file values on the line that are within that one range, write a new .txt with that range and then repeat for subsequent ranges.

Something like:

```
inputrange = sys.argv[1]
inputfile = sys.argv[2]
outputname = sys.argv[3]

range_handle = open(inputrange, "r")
input_fhandle = open(inputfile, "r")
output_fhandle = open(outputname, "w")
for line in range_handle:
    #read in lines & store values of first second range... assume line.strip() and .split() have already been done
    first_range = float(storage_lines[0])
    second_range = float(storage_lines[1])
    for linez in input_fhandle:
        #assume .split() and .split() have been performed to create a list of vals of everything in line and that indices of the list have been assigned to variables -- in this case thing1, thing2, thing3 are some of those indices
                average: float = (float(thing1) + float(thing2) + float(thing3)/3.0)
output_fhandle = output_fhandle + "_" + str(first_range) + "_" + str(second_range) + "_range.txt"
        if(average >= first_range and average <= second_range)):
            output_fhandle.write(f"writes whole line of data to file")
```

Specifically, I want my output file to look something like output_fhandle_(first_range)_(second_range)_range.txt
But the error I am getting is:

```
output_fhandle = output_fhandle + "_" + str(first_range) + "_" + str(second_range) + "_range.txt"
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: '_io.TextIOWrapper' and 'str'
```

Where am I going wrong in my syntax and how can I make sure each file I am creating is unique to that read in line of my range.txt file?

Thank you

Comment: output_fhandle is a file handler, as the variable name would suggest. Here, you're trying to append a string to a file handler, which doesn't make much sense. You say you want the output to be "`output_fhandle_...`"; does that mean you want to output the filename? If so, you probably want to use outputname instead of the file handler.

Comment: No I don't want to output a filename, I want to write to a new file the user input for argv[3] as argv[3]_range1_range2_range.txt . I did what you are suggesting and it is now not error-ing out, but the file.txt is not named appropriately, and is simply argv[3]. I've already assigned the name of the .txt when I set the outputname = argv[3] .... and then I opened that output_fhandle with the intention to write to it -- I don't know if this is possible to append these two ranges after the fact that I've already defined it....?

Comment: Ah, I see. If you want to create a new file called `{argv[3]}_range1_range2_range.txt`, then you probably want to define that as a string using something like `new_outputname = outputname + str(first_range) + ...`, and then create a *new* file handler that takes in `new_outputname` as an argument.

Comment: Thank you. I am still struggling with a conditional statement but I am now creating the correct output files.